# updating MySQL from xcode to PHP by using HTTP-POST method

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode, http-post

I'm writing a iPad apps to connect with a MySQL server via PHP web services.  So far I'm fine with the query function.
However, when I use the POST method to communicate with the PHP, it is not work and I have no clue.  It is just a simple application as I'm newbie on Xcode.

I cannot POST the value "report_id=1" to the PHP server, any problems on my code?

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSURL *connection = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost/deletescript.php"];

NSString *string=@"report_id=1";

NSMutableString *httpBodyString=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];

[request setURL:connection];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[httpBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSLog(@"ABC"@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

return YES;
}
```

error message from Xcode console:

```
2015-01-12 17:48:02.468 connMySQL[856:287936] *** WARNING: CFMachPortSetInvalidationCallBack() called on a CFMachPort with a Mach port (0x6b13) which does not have any send rights.  This is not going to work.  Callback function: 0x18360d06c
2015-01-12 17:48:02.509 connMySQL[856:287936] Stream 0x170108820 is sending an event before being opened
2015-01-12 17:48:02.576 connMySQL[856:287871] ABC

Notice:  Undefined index: report_id in C:\Share\Apache2.2\htdocs\deletescript.php on line 12

DELETE FROM car WHERE report_id = 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
2015-01-12 17:48:02.577 connMySQL[856:287871] Connection Successful
```

The variable is not passed to PHP by HTTP-POST successfully...
Thanks in advance for any feedback.  Or any suggestion in updating a MySQL server from iOS application is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined report_id? Did you mean $_POST[$report_id] or $_POST"report_id"?

You can bebug your PHP code by dumping text output.

Try the following:

var_dump($_POST); 
OR
die("Some string output");

Comment: You mean on my php?  report_id is one of my column on table 'car'.